# How to backward generate a db logic diagram with mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I just want to generate db logic diagram from being specified tables within MySql Database.
I have installed Mysql workbench 5.2.25, anyone can tell me how to use the tool to generated it?

Answer (score 0):

WB has a "generate EER diagram from existent database" option. BTW, you have a really old AN version. Go and get a newer one!